# Error en php, con if

Tags: php, codeigniter

Este es el error que me aparece,

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>       Type: ParseError
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\upa\application\controllers\admin\Usuarios.php
>
> Line Number: 53

y esta es mi codigo:

```
$action2 = "<td id='delboxbox".$r->id."'><label class='switch'><input type='checkbox'".
if ($r->state==2) {.'checked'.}." ><span class='slider'></span></label></td>";
```

puede que sea un error minimo, pero he mirado y no lo he hallado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es mala idea imprimir html en php, pero intenta así:

```
$action2 = "<td id='delboxbox".$r->id."'><label class='switch'><input type='checkbox' ".(($r->state==2) ? 'checked': '')." ><span class='slider'></span></label></td>";
```

eso debería resolver tu problema, Saludos

Comment: Asi es, es correcto, muchas gracias, es era el problema

Comment: recuerda marcar solucionada tu pregunta para ayuda de otros. Saludos

Comment: Si claro, solo me faltan 2 minutos para marcarla.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que no estas comparando en tu if:

```
if ($r->state==2) // esto es comparacio

if ($r->state=2) // esto es igualacion
```

Comment: Si, es correcto, igual con el cambio, me sigue apareciendo el error

Comment: pero donde tiene ese echo? debes poner esa linea

Comment: Perdon, ya lo corrijo, el error es este...

Comment: no puedes usar if concatenado de esa manera, revisa mi respuesta para que veas la solucion